# Replace node name XML with regular expresión Notepad++

Tags: xml, replace, notepad++

Edited

I am trying to replace the node name with regular expressions on Notepad++. I hace something similar to this:

```
<Vehicle_name color="green" type="sub" extra="panoramic roof">
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
  </Vehicle>

 <Vehicle_brand color="green" type="sub" extra="panoramic roof">
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
  </Vehicle>
```

And I want to get this

```
<Vehicle_name color="green" type="sub" extra="panoramic roof">
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <InvoiceDateTime InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
  </Vehicle_name>

 <Vehicle_brand color="green" type="sub" extra="panoramic roof">
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
    <AuthorizationCode InvoiceChargeCents="63" OptionCode="nothing"/>
  </Vehicle_brand>
```

Tnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<Vehicle(_\w+).+?</Vehicle\K>`
- Replace with: `$1>`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<Vehicle            # literally
(_\w+)              # group 1, 1 or more word character
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
</Vehicle           # literally
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
>                   # >
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1
>               # >
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]